# Flooding RAM using an infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I've created an infinite loop to try and flood the RAM with a string. However, I get the "Memory Exceeded" error very quickly and I assume this is some preventative method in Python to stop this happening. Is there a way to change this infinite loop to bypass the prevention methods? Or a way to turn it off? Here is my loop:

```
array = []

while True:
    array.append('test')
```

Comment: From what I've read, there's no Python memory limit, it's just limited by the system resource limits. See the `limit` command on Unix.

Comment: I just want to point out that you're not flooding the memory with the string, but with the array only. No matter how many references to "test" string you have, there is only one "test" string in memory. This is by implementation.

Comment: Can you provide documentation about that, @ElmoVanKielmo

Comment: @JonSurrell: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id compare `id('test')` and `id('test')`.

Comment: Just execute these 4 lines of code and you will see: 1. `a = "test"` 2. `b = "test"` 3. `print id(a)` 4. `print id(b)`

Answer (score 1):

What does very quickly mean?

Let's assume creating and appending that string is about 200 bytes (assuming 8 bit addresses, and the pointers required in `PyObject` to dominate the memory usage), then filling let's say 8GB of RAM `== 2**3 * 2**30 B` would take `1/25 * 2**30 ~= 40 * 2**20 ~= 40 millons` iterations through your loop -- which might only take a few seconds.

EDIT: Had a look at the actual CPython 2.7 implementation. Yields 40B space for an empty list, plus 8B per element. So this will take 1 billion iterations to occupy 8GB of Ram, not counting the string objects.

EDIT2: Tried this on my oldish laptop; consumes about 16MB/s, which would, considering the 8B/iteration approach, mean that python does 2e6 loop iterations per second. Nice!

EDIT3: either your computer is blazingly fast, or you have really little RAM.

Comment: Ok yeah it is only a few seconds, however when I capture the RAM, my "test" array doesn't seem to appear at all. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: probably, yes. What are you expecting to see? A list is really just a 40 byte header followed by a vector of addresses on CPython/x86_64. How much Ram, which implementation, which os, which platform are we talking about, anyway?

Comment: `"Not counting the string objects"` Assuming CPython there are no multiple string objects created in this loop. See comments to the question.

Comment: I've been doing this in Windows 7 using a virtual machine, I've allocated it 4GB RAM space. I'd ideally like a large portion of the RAM to be flooded with the "test" array so I can test it's retention period.

Comment: @ajh: won't happen, because there will be only one "test" string object in memory, also because that is not how lists work in python (they hold pointers to objects, not the objects themselves, obviously), or how memory paging works. Python is one of the worst choices you can do when wanting to explicitely manipulate RAM; when modifying user space RAM, you will never get continous physical RAM. I think you have a lot of misconceptions about how memory is handled in Python, operating systems and modern-day computers.